# Confusing if statement in php

Tags: php, if-statement, legacy-code

I'm refreshing some older code (someone else wrote), and came across this:

```
if ( empty ( $role_data["role_id" == 1]))
```

what are the reasons (if any) one would use the above instead of?:

```
if ( $role_data["role_id"] != 1)
```

IMO readability is worse and it's more code. Performance isn't a factor here.

--EDIT--

I should mention, that the expected input($role_data["role_id"]) is a number between 0 - 5 (inclusive)



--MORE INFO--

I've missunderstood the code the first time around.
But here's what's happening:

```
$role_id = htmlspecialchars ( mysql_real_escape_string ( $_GET["role_id"] ) );
$role_data = $db->fctSelectData ( "core_role" , "`role_id` = '" . $role_id . "'" );
```

This goes to get the permissions for creating the role. But if given an invalid `$role_id` in the first place (via the $_GET parameter), it returns nothing, hence checking for an empty value in:

```
if ( empty ( $role_data["role_id" == 1] ) )
```

I'm still not fully clear of why it's written this way

Comment: `if ( empty ( $role_data["role_id" == 1]))` !== `if ( $role_data["role_id"] != 1)`. Your old code is: `if ( empty ( $role_data["role_id" == 1]))` -> `if ( empty ($role_data[0]) )` (Because `"role_id" == 1` = FALSE and because of type juggling = 0)

Comment: @Rizier123 is correct both are different.

Comment: It's someone attempting to be cute and show off, while failing miserably at both. That or total cargo-cult programming

Comment: @MarcB Look at the `
Loose comparisons with ==` table: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php  First one: `TRUE` and `"php"` and second one: `1` and `"php"`

Comment: yeah, I need to go have some coffee or something...

Comment: @MarcB I would go for a cold shower :) It's like 37°C(100°F) here.

Comment: 15c/59f here due to incipient nuclear winter due to forest fire smoke haze.

Comment: Thanks guys, I learn new stuff about php every day

Comment: Regarding the comment from Rizier123, could you please provide us with some more code to find out why the author wants to find out  `empty ($role_data[0])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
if (empty($role_data["role_id" == 1]))
```

Gets translated into...

```
if (empty($role_data[0]))
```

...by the PHP interpreter. This code might be a "joke", a funny hack or an error as the line:

```
if (empty($role_data["role_id"]) == 1)
```

..sort of makes sense.